# Downgrade Ubuntu 22.10 to 20.04 for ROS

Tags: ros

I would like to downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 is it is officially supported by ROS Noetic Ninjemys. What are the exact steps that I can follow without breaking my machine?

Comment: There is no way to "downgrade" safely.  The only solution for your system is to backup the data you want to keep to external media, and then clean install Ubuntu 20.04.  However, keep in mind that 20.04 is *old* and 22.04 is the current LTS.  Unless you absolutely need Ubuntu 20.04, you should use Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: As per the ROS Noetic Ninjemys website, it officially supports the 20.04. I could not install ROS on 22.10 so yeah I have to clean the install. Plus, I am wondering if there is an option to just downgrade it to 20.04 without losing my data, using a bootable flash.

Comment: **There is no Downgrade option.**  There is no downgrade on the bootable USB media either.  Your only option is a clean install after you back up the data you need/want to keep to external media.

Comment: I’m not familiar with ROS at all, but would Docker be an option?

Comment: Cab you run 20.04 in a virtual machine instead?

Comment: I'll provide an FYI, but you didn't specify what 22.10 product you're trying to downgrade as that very much matters.  You can non-destructively re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system (*this works with flavors too being desktops!*) which will cause all Ubuntu repository to be re-installed automatically (*if available for that release*) and no user file/config is touched... As there is no check on release; you can re-install the same, a newer or in fact an older release too!   But please read next comment first,

Comment: HOWEVER there is nothing done to ensure data modified by newer programs is readable via the older programs; so that's homework you need to perform yourself package by package if data matters to you.   This can have consequences to your data if the older version of the app can't deal with your datafiles modified by newer versions of the same app...  I've experienced problems with this (*not easy to detect either!*) so ensure you do your homework well before using it for every package/app where data in that app works for you.  This is for Desktop installs only I'm talking about.